# Get HTML text length by Angularjs

Tags: jquery, html

I have declared text type in HTML and trying to get the length by Angular JS but everytime it's getting as '1'. Can anyone help me to get text length

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" maxlength ="256" size ="100" class="chk-agreement" name="fav-foods" ng-required="true">
```

**AngularJs**

```
var texElem = $(document).find("input[type='text'].chk-agreement");
var textElem = texElem.length;
```

Comment: That's not angularjs in any way, read about [ngModel](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) if you're talking about the length of the value of the input

Comment: You're getting the number of elements from `find()`.  If you want to get the length of the text, you need to get the value first.

Comment: What is the length of the input field? What number do you think it is? Also, you are using Jquery.
It gives "1" Because JQuery searches for the input fields that match the selector and it only finds one hence "1" is the length.

Comment: How do i get the length from value?

Answer (score 0):

What you are using is JQuery and not AngularJS, though this is what you should try.

```
var texElem = $(document).find("input[type='text'].chk-agreement");
var textElem = $(texElem).val().length;
```